# How do I display a MathJax String in a SwiftUI ScrollView?

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview, wkwebview, mathjax

I receive a `MathJax` `String` from an `API` response which needs to be shown in a `WKWebView` in `SwiftUI`. Here's a sample `String`

```
"<img alt=\"\" height=\"2305\" src=\"https:\/\/s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com\/infinitestudent-images\/ckeditor_assets\/pictures\/37732\/content_types_of_combustion.jpg\" width=\"800\" \/>"
```

Here's the code that I've tried:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct Model: Codable {
    var mathjaxBody: String?
    var answer: Answer
}

struct MathJaxView: View {

    let model: Model

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            AnswerSectionView(answer: model.answer)
            HTMLView(htmlString: model.mathjaxBody)
                .frame(minWidth: 100, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}

struct HTMLView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var htmlString: String?

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        WKWebView(frame: .zero)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        guard let string = htmlString else { return }
        uiView.loadHTMLString(string, baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```

It need to be in a `ScrollView` with a few different details on top of it, which is displayed properly in the `ScrollView`. But, the `HTMLView` doesn't show up. I tried adding `.frame(minWidth: 100, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100, maxHeight: .infinity)` But still doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to simply calculate the required height from `evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight")` method and apply it to the `WebView` component with a few other methods.

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {

    var htmlString: String?

    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: WebViewModel

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
        webView.backgroundColor = .clear
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        guard let string = htmlString else { return }
        uiView.loadHTMLString(string, baseURL: nil)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {

        private var viewModel: WebViewModel

        init(viewModel: WebViewModel) {
            self.viewModel = viewModel
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState") { (complete, error) in
                if complete != nil {
                    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight") { (height, error) in
                        if let height = height as? CGFloat, self.viewModel.contentHeight == 0 {
                            self.viewModel.contentHeight = height * 0.4
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(viewModel: viewModel)
    }
}

class WebViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0
}

struct MathJaxView: View {

    let model: Model

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            AnswerSectionView(answer: model.answer)
            WebView(htmlString: model.mathjaxBody)
                .environmentObject(webViewModel)
                .frame(height: webViewModel.contentHeight)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        }
    }
}
```